# Using SQL for an auto scheduler?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, automation

I had a question regarding SQL and if you could code it properly to do auto scheduling.

Example

A shipment could come to a store Monday-Friday, but there could only be a certain amount of shipments during this week and it depends which worker was available. I'll run down things in order that way it's not too confusing.

A) A shipment can only stop twice a day, but it cannot stop on a day that has any shipments the day before or the day after. So if Monday had 2 shipments, there would be no stops on Tuesday. If Wednesday has 2 shipments, you could not have any stops Tuesday/Thursday.

B) A shipment can only be so big on these days. If two shipments are both UNDER 1000 pounds, then we can schedule both, but if a shipment is OVER 1000 pounds, then we can only schedule one for that day.

C) One of the two workers must unload each shipment. So lets say that A already has 1 shipment on Monday, I need it to go to B for the 2nd shipment on that Monday.

I understand that SQL cannot accept user input directly, so don't worry about this. Using getdate() would be sufficient enough.

I started on this code and got a little bit in, but the while loop was running for forever (>30 seconds) and I thought it was almost impractical at that point.

Curious if this is doable and the best approach to do this. I'm assuming that C# or something would be loads easier to do with, but wondering about SQL.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Depend on your rdbms, for example `Postgresql` has a `PgAgent` So you can schedule repeated task

Comment: When you added the SQL tag, you were shown a big red popup that suggested you add another tag for the specific DBMS you were using, because the features and syntax between them varies widely. Why did you choose to ignore it and not provide one?

Comment: I did not see that nor am I familiar enough with stackoverflow to know about that. I did not CHOOSE to ignore anything, so please stop assuming and then proceeding to belittle people based off of a simple mistake.

Comment: Please post your schema, sample data, and your code.